# New contributor pop up creates a scrollbar inside the question

Tags: bug, scrolling, new-contributor-indicator

This seems to be a recent change... When I put the mouse over the new contributor indicator, the little pop up is created but seems to be confined *within* the question container -- creating an off-putting scrollbar:

[image]

This is on Chrome in Windows.

Comment: Man, I got sniped cause I was drawing my freehand circle...